# How can I remove a nested key-value pair, whose value has a deeper nested array with a specific value by using jq

Tags: json, jq

I am currently trying to filter out some path values from a swagger json document, by using jq.

The JSON looks something like this:

```json
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "1.0.2",
    "title": "Some API"
  },
  "host": "example.com",
  "basePath": "/",
  "paths": {
    "/api/companies": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [ "company-tag" ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": { "$ref": "#/definitions/CompanyDTO" }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/api/account": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [ "account-tag" ],
        "operationId": "getAccount",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": { "$ref": "#/definitions/UserDTO" }
          }
        }
      },
      "post": {
        "tags": [ "account-tag" ],
        "operationId": "createAccount",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": { "$ref": "#/definitions/UserDTO" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to filter the **paths** values, so that I can get only the paths that contain a specific tag inside the **tags** array.

For example: if I want to get the paths for the **account-tag** the JSON should look like this after filtering:

```json
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "1.0.2",
    "title": "Some API"
  },
  "host": "example.com",
  "basePath": "/",
  "paths": {
    "/api/account": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [ "account-tag" ],
        "operationId": "getAccount",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": { "$ref": "#/definitions/UserDTO" }
          }
        }
      },
      "post": {
        "tags": [ "account-tag" ],
        "operationId": "createAccount",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": { "$ref": "#/definitions/UserDTO" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Ikegami's second suggestion worked as expected.
Here is my final [solution](https://jqplay.org/s/4VmYatAx--)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume all methods (`get`, `post`, etc) of a given path share the same tags, we can simply use the following:

```
.paths |= with_entries( select( .value[].tags | index("account-tag") ) )
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/R5Nt_sXa9N) on jqplay

---

If that assumption doesn't hold, we'll need to filter at two levels.

```
.paths |= with_entries(
   .value |= with_entries(
      select( .value.tags | index("account-tag") )
   ) |
   select( .value | length > 0 )
)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/yESry30aVp) on jqplay

or

```
.paths |= with_entries(
   .value = (
      .value |
      with_entries(
         select( .value.tags | index("account-tag") )
      ) |
      select( length > 0 )
   )
)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/w8GXYL8b5Y) on jqplay

(I hate that I have to use `.value = ( .value | ... )` instead of `.value |= ( ... )` here.)

Comment: The first assumption cannot be made. However your second suggestion seems to work as expected. 

I would like to mark your Answer as correct :) can you add this little demo to your answer? https://jqplay.org/s/4VmYatAx--
 
It contains the fully working query with the example from the question

Comment: Also checked with the bigger json that I have lying around locally and it seems to work as expected. Thank you a lot :)

Comment: I purposefully didn't use the JSON from the OP because it doesn't show that the code works. It has no URL for which the `get` and the `post` have different tags.

Comment: Yeah, the json sort of evolved during the discussion in the already deleted answer, so while you were tinkering the question was edited. Sorry about that.
I also realized that it is good enough to add the demo to the Question, so no worries about that. Again thanks it saved me a lot of time :D